# Three elements inline bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to put elements inline.

Here's my code:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <div data-bind="foreach: myList">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="" data-bind="value: Id(), attr: { id: Id() }, checked: $root.ids" />
                        <span style="padding-bottom: 15px; vertical-align: middle;" data-bind="text: t1()" />
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="TEST" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

Now It looks like:

checkbox, label

input

I want to put all elements in one line like:
checkbox label input

checkbox label input

checkbox label input

Comment: Post a bootply code of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using Bootstrap's `form-inline` class.

[**Working Example**](http://www.bootply.com/6RrChfp86I)

```
<div class="form-inline">
  <div data-bind="foreach: myList">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="" data-bind="value: Id(), attr: { id: Id() }, checked: $root.ids">
        <span style="padding-bottom: 15px; vertical-align: middle;" data-bind="text: t1()"></span>
      </label>
    </div>   
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="TEST">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div data-bind="foreach: myList">
        <label class="checkbox col-sm-6">
            <input type="checkbox" id="" data-bind="value: Id(), attr: { id: Id() }, checked: $root.ids" />
            <span style="padding-bottom: 15px; vertical-align: middle;" data-bind="text: t1()" />
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-6" >
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="TEST" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can change `col-sm-6` to change width..

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="TEST">
  </div>
</form>
```